# First Value in UniqueIdentifier SqlDbType

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I need the first number in uniqueidentifier sqldbtype of one of my table.
 I should hard-code it in my application since that one is specifial with other records and I do not want to recognize it by its name but rather it's ID.
 Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'